# C#-"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime" exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this code in my controller.this code gives an exception when i'm trying to loop through a DataSet.The exception is given on different rows when i run the project several times.(The exception is not happen at exact row)

The exception is;

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

```
DateTime arrDate = DateTime.Parse(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["CheckInDate"].ToString());
```

i tried this too;

```
DateTime createdDate = DateTime.ParseExact(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["CheckInDate"].ToString(), "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

but it is not working yet..

the value of the row is `2/9/2016 21:20`

Comment: What's the value of the `CheckInDate` you are passing? We'd need to see that to start with. If it's a `dateimte` field you can cast to `DateTime` without the parse.

Comment: My guess is that the string is not a valid date time....?!

Comment: @Lloyd Strings like 2/9/2016 21:20 ..

Comment: First of all i'd try using TryParse instead and check what strings are failing

Comment: `DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("2/9/2016 21:20", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` works ok to me BTW

Comment: @Pikoh - that's because 2 and 9 are both valid for days and months. Try it with days > 12.

Comment: @ChrisF `DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("2/22/2016 21:20", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` works too :)

Comment: @Pikoh I was more thinking of 22/2/2016 :)

Comment: @ChrisF that would obviously don't work unless we use a different CultureInfo. But i assume the format OP is trying to cast is (M/d/YYYY... because the sample he is giving (2/9/2016 21:20 ..)

Answer (score 4):

You just have to cast it to the right type which seems to be `DateTime`, no need to parse:

```
DateTime arrDate = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].Field<DateTime>("CheckInDate");
```

If it's actually a string(why is that so?) use `M/d/yyyy` instead of `MM/dd/yyyy`:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("2/9/2016 21:20", "M/d/yyyy HH:mm", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
```

Comment: ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["CheckInDate"].ToString() will pass 2/19/2016 21:20 kind of strings

Comment: @ThilinaDeSilva: yes, because `ToString` returns a string even if it was a `DateTime`. Have you used my code? What returns `....Field<DateTime>("CheckInDate")`?

Answer (score 1):

`ParseExact` requires that your string *exactly* matches the pattern you are parsing against.

Your pattern has "MM/dd" which requires double digit months and days ("01/29" or "10/02" or "01/02") but you are only passing in single digit months and days ("2/9").

You either need to change the pattern to accept single digits or change the string to pass double digits.

Answer (score 0):

you need to know in which format the date is retrieved then parse it with the proper format

```
DateTime dt=DateTime.ParseExact(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["CheckInDate"].ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

if this format is not apropiate for the current culture (the language and region of the application)

```
// for example language English and region Canada
DateTime dt=DateTime.Parse(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["CheckInDate"].ToString(), new CultureInfo("en-CA"));
```

OR

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-CA");
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["CheckInDate"].ToString()); //uses the current Thread's culture
```

For more informations, check out [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Try below,

```
If ( ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["CheckInDate"] != null ) {
// your code goes here...
DateTime arrDate = DateTime.Parse(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["CheckInDate"].ToString());
}
```

Comment: I would always use String.IsNullOrEmpty to validate strings

Comment: Well. Author of this question didn't added that. So I thought that there may be issue of check of nothing. This is not a valid reason to rate down this answer.